# rekit with github pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I am trying to setup my react application on github pages with uses rekit. There are no errors but the build is empty. Standard react create app works fine with gh-pages but application created using rekit does not.

Answer (score 0):

By default Rekit builds the project into the "build" folder, have you checked if it's empty? If not, you can verify it by the default build server at http://localhost:6078 by default.

Another possible reason is, Rekit uses React Router, when uploaded to gh-pages the root path is like "http://supnate.github.io/prj-name" but the local dev server may runs at root path "/". If so, you may update "src/common/routeConfig.js" to set the root path to your project name. And you need to test it at local with "http://localhost:6076/prj-name".

Comment: "By default Rekit builds the project into the "build" folder, have you checked if it's empty? If not, you can verify it by the default build server at http://localhost:6078 by default." - this works fine

gh-pages still show blank page :(